# Getting a pivot table to only filter one set of values?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create a dual axis chart; a bar graph of total calls with a line representing percent of calls that are during business hours.

My source data is a list of calls that have the following information: session ID, duration minutes, business hours?(y/n), and OS type.

My thoughts is to have a count of session ID to calculate the total number of calls, and then filter a count of business hours? to only include the Y values. The problem i'm running in to is that it also filters out the count of session ID instead of leaving it alone.

Is there a way to do this that I'm not thinking of? Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fully grasp the specifics of the chart you wish. And since, being a newbie, I can't add a comment, here's an attempt of providing a solution based on guesses of your need.

So, I think you can probably get what you want through a pivot table:[image]

The specifics of the pivot table are in the screenshot above, plus the following : right-click on any "Number of session ID" value, and then (roughly translated from my french Excel) `Display values` > `% of row total`, like this:[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying! The chart that I am wanting to create is a bar chart of a count of the session ID over time; so 5 calls in January, 10 in February, etc. I would like to add a line chart on top of that, that shows what the percent of calls are that are "y", meaning percent of calls that are during business hours.

Comment: So your source data also bears some date information, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file For Data as under, say,

Sr. No. SID Minutes Business Type
1   A   25      Y
2   A   18      N
3   A   36      N
4   A   10      Y
5   A   18      Y
6   A   14      N
7   B   32      Y
8   B   14      N
9   B   5       Y
10  B   32      N
11  C   15      Y
12  C   32      Y
13  C   12      Y
14  C   25      N
15  C   18      Y
16  C   36      Y
17  C   10      Y
18  C   18      N
19  C   14      Y
20  D   32      N
21  E   14      Y
22  E   5       N
23  E   32      Y
24  E   15      Y
25  E   32      Y

Where Headings in First Row are as under :

1   Five Columns with Headings
    Sr. No., SID, Duration Minutes, Business Type, SID_Business_Call

2   Sr. No. : 1, 2, 3…..
    SID : A, B, C, D, E.
3   Duration Minutes : 25, 18, 36….

4   Business Type : Y, N, Y, Y, Y, N, …

Name the Ranges as Under :

Range   "$B$2:$B$26"   is given a name  "SID"
Range   "$C$2:$BC26"   is given a name  "Duration"
Range   "$E$2:$E$26"   is given a name  "YesNo"

Now write Formulas as under

5   SID_Business_Call : Formula 
    IF(D2="Y",B2,"")
6   Then Below the Data
    Enter Column Headings in Cell B30, C30, D30…M30 as under
    Session ID, Total Calls, Business Count, Non Business Count, 
    % of Business Count, Total Duration, % of Total Time,
    Business Duration Minutes, % of Total Business Duration
    % of SID Business Duration, Average Business Minutes
    and in M30..Non Business Duration Minutes
7   Under B30 write in B31 "A", B32 "B"….B35 "E"

8   In C31 enter formula  "= COUNTIF(SID,B31)"
    Copy this formula down the Cell up to  C35
9   In cell D31 Enter the formula "=COUNTIF(YesNo,B31)"
    Copy this formula down the Cell upto D35
10  In cell E31 Enter the formula "=C31-D31"
    Copy this formula down the Cell upto E35
11  In cell F31 Enter the formula "=D31/C31*100"
    Copy this formula down the Cell upto F35
12  In cell G31 Enter the formula "=SUMIFS(Duration,SID,B31)"
    Copy this formula down the Cell upto G35
13  In cell H31 Enter the formula "=G31/$G$37*100"
    Copy this formula down the Cell upto H35
14  In Cell I31 Enter the formula =SUMIF(YesNo,B31,Duration)
    Copy Down the Cell I35

15  In Cell B37 Enter the text " TOTAL"
16  In Cell B39 Enter the Text "  %  "
17  In Cell C37 Enter the formula " =SUM(C31:C35)"
    Copy this in Cells : D37, E37, G37 and so on

It is little lengthy. I have both data, results and formulas in Excel Worksheet but I dont know how to share worksheet with you, to avoid all these explanations.

Thanks.

Sorry if found lengthy.

Comment: The results of above data is as under

Comment: Session ID Total Calls Buisness Count Non Business Count % of Business Count Total Duration % Of Total Time Business Duration Minutes % of Total Business Duration % of SID Business Duration Average Business Minutes Non Business Duration Minutes
A 6 3 3 50 121 23.54 53 16.56 43.80 17.67 68
B 4 2 2 50 83 16.15 37 11.56 44.58 18.50 46
C 9 7 2 78 180 35.02 137 42.81 76.11 19.57 43
D 1 0 1 0 32 6.23 0 0.00 0.00 0.00 32
E 5 4 1 80 98 19.07 93 29.06 94.90 23.25 5
           
Total 25 16 9  514 100.00 320 100.00  78.99 194.00
           
%  64 36    62.26    37.74